# Images Moving using UITouches in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have 3 images.I am moving those images using the UITouches methods.My problem is when i am moving the first image,if the first image center is equal to second image then those are appearing like one image.But I want only first image should be move and second image should not move and also first image should bring to front.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must add with this order:
-third image
-second image
-first image

With this order, the first image will be put in the front

I hope it'll help